# ionic - angularjs - list not rendering after reopening app on android device

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have this mobile app where it lists a record of encoded transport/taxi receipt. The first page seen when opening the app is the list of receipt.

**templates/list-view.html**

```
<ion-item class="card item item-light" ng-click="edit({{receipt.id}})" ng-repeat="receipt in receipts|orderBy:'receiptDate'">
   ...
</ion-item>
   ...
<ion-footer-bar class="bar-subfooter taxi-subfooter">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col">
        <button ng-click="addRecord(-1)" class="button button-block"><i class="icon ion-plus-round"></i></button>
    </div>
</div>
```

if I click the item or if I click the button with `addRecord(-1)`, it will go to the add/edit receipt page:

**templates/edit-receipt.html**

```
<ion-content padding="true" class="has-header has-footer taxi-has-subfooter">
    <div class="table">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col title">Paper receipt provided?</div>
            <div class="col taxi-col">
                <label class="toggle toggle-balanced">
                    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="bindReceipt.hasReceipt">                       
                    <div class="track taxi-track">
                        <div class="handle taxi-handle"></div>
                    </div>
                </label>
                <input type="hidden" ng-model="bindReceipt.id" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col title">Date</div>
            <div class="col taxi-col"><input type="date" ng-model="bindReceipt.receiptDate" /></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col title">Vendor</div>
            <div class="col taxi-col"><input type="text" placeholder="Name of the Taxi" ng-model="bindReceipt.taxiVendor" /></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col title">Fare</div>
            <div class="col taxi-col"><input type="tel" placeholder="0.00" ng-model="bindReceipt.fare" /></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</ion-content>
<ion-footer-bar class="bar-subfooter taxi-subfooter">
        <div class="row"> <!-- update() functions also as add -->
            <div class="col taxi-col"><button class="button button-block" ng-click="update()">{{transType}}</button></div>
        </div>
    </ion-footer-bar>
```

What I did in its behavior for back button of the phone is if the state is on the add/edit page, it will just go back to the list page, and if the state is on the list page, no matter how many times the user will go from/to list and edit pages, it should exit the app (no going back of the app history). So, I used `navigator.app.exitApp()` for the backbutton on the list page.

templates/list-view.html uses ReceiptsCtrl controller so I put there my event listener for backbutton:

```
app.controller('ReceiptsCtrl', function($window, $scope, $filter, $state, $http, $ionicPopup, Receipts) {

    $scope.receipts = Receipts.getReceipts();

    $scope.historyBack = function(evt) {
        if(evt != null) {
          if(evt.preventDefault) {
            evt.preventDefault();
          }
        }

        var location = $window.location.href;
        if(location.charAt(location.length-1) === '/') {

            navigator.app.exitApp(); // exit the application
        } else {
            history.go(-1);
        }

      }

      document.addEventListener('backbutton', $scope.historyBack, false);

});
```

services.js

```
.factory('Receipts', function($window, $filter) {

  var receipts = JSON.parse($window.localStorage.getItem('receipts')) || [];
  return {
    getReceipts: function() {return receipts;}

  }

});
```

Here's my problem, I have this scenario in my app after I build and run in android:

1. opening the app. 0 record initially
2. add two items - 2 records in the list page
3. currently on the list page then exit the app (navigator.app.exitApp() triggers)
4. open the app again, 2 records is still there
5. add one item - 3 records in the list page
6. on the list page again then exit app
7. open the app, **missing list**

Screenshot of the scenario [here](http://s1067.photobucket.com/user/rponce95/media/Development%20Screenies/taxi-02_zpspmzet0n3.png.html)

That is not happening when I do not use the backbutton event listener, but I find it annoying if it go through history swinging between list and edit page before exiting the app.

I use `$window.localStorage` for storing data then pass it on `$scope.receipts` for the list `ng-repeat`, I tried debugging it by inserting `alert()` with the receipt object fetched from localStorage as argument. There is a value on the alert message but listing is not working. Another thing also is that it can still compute the total fare from the `$scope.receipts` (as stated in the screenshot also).

Many thanks.

Comment: can you make a plunker plz ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the issue. I have no idea how to replicate it on browser but I was able to catch it in Android Device Monitor

```
11-12 03:08:23.861: I/chromium(30444): [INFO:CONSOLE(139)] "Error: [ngRepeat:dupes] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.3/ngRepeat/dupes?p0=[Some data from my app URL encoded. It's too long]
11-12 03:08:23.861: I/chromium(30444):     at Error (<anonymous>)
11-12 03:08:23.861: I/chromium(30444):     at file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.min.js:37:416
11-12 03:08:23.861: I/chromium(30444):     at file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.min.js:309:261
11-12 03:08:23.861: I/chromium(30444):     at Object.fn (file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.min.js:162:168)
11-12 03:08:23.861: I/chromium(30444):     at n.$digest (file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.min.js:163:259)
11-12 03:08:23.861: I/chromium(30444):     at n.$apply (file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.min.js:166:269)
11-12 03:08:23.861: I/chromium(30444):     at l (file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.min.js:118:152)
11-12 03:08:23.861: I/chromium(30444):     at F (file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.min.js:122:187)
11-12 03:08:23.861: I/chromium(30444):     at XMLHttpRequest.K.onload (file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.min.js:123:220)", source: file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.min.js (139)
```

I searched about **ngRepeat:dupes** - AngularJS doesn't allow duplicates and recommended to use `track by` to avoid errors like this. So I changed my code and use it on `ng-repeat`.

With correct format, I wrote:

```
ng-repeat="receipt in receipts|orderBy:'receiptDate'| filter:receiptFilter track by receipt.id"
```

I tried `track by` right after the `orderBy` but does not work. I found that it should be after a `filter` in order to work. So I made a `receiptFilter` variable under my controller (something empty string like `$scope.receiptFilter = "";`) just to have something harmless in my result of `ng-repeat`.

Before resorting to `track by receipt.id`, I tried `track by $index` but the error persists. I look for answers and found that it is not safe to use `$index` when using `orderBy`.

**In summary, when sorting (`orderBy`), use `track by <a unique key>` (not `$index`).**

I hope this answer will help and any more supplements on this one will be much appreciated. :)